# API Documentation for WebRTC Android Library

Tags: android, webrtc, apprtcdemo

I'm learning WebRTC and I have found its JavaScript documentation quiet good. But then, I want to work with webrtc on Android. So I found [this page](http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/). After Adding the libraries I cannot find documentation like it is for JS. There is AppRTC but then I find it confusing rather than expressive (that might be my own problem, not sure).

So where do I go for documentation for Android WebRTC library? Is there any tutorial or simple reference that is valid as of 2020? Many data I have found are 5 or more years, and seems outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [documentation](https://www.audiocodes.com/media/13259/webrtc-android-client-sdk-api-reference-guide.pdf) created by `AudioCodes` company and the publish date is 03 August 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I found [very useful Github Project](https://github.com/IhorKlimov/Android-WebRtc). Two years old as of 2020, but very informative and simple. Once you get the basics of WebRTC you can dive on the code. This works well in conjuction with [WebRTC Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web)

Answer (score 1):

It's weirdly hard to find documentation for this, but I've found the source code here the most helpful:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc